# Azure DevOps - setting,passing and overwriting variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm currently working with azure infrastructure where crucial "vulnerable" components as KeyVault and Storage Account are set to "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses". As per demand of the owner, we are tasked to use Microsoft hosted agents I'm trying dance around this option. My Service connection has all the needed accesses to modify network rules. My current solution work fine with adding new rules but I would like to implement post-run clean up to not clutter and secure resources with removing stale IP rules.

I came up with a solution that utilizes template as pre-run task and post-cleanup.

Add IP template

```yaml
  - name: service_connection_name
    type: string
  - name: storage_account_name
    type: string
  - name: resource_group_name
    type: string
  - name: keyvault_name
    type: string
  - name: PUBLIC_IP
    type: string
    default: " "

steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Adding ip
    name: AddIP
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.service_connection_name}}
      scriptType: "bash"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      inlineScript: |
        export MY_IP=$(curl -s ifconfig.me)
        echo "My IP: $MY_IP"
        echo "Public IP: ${{parameters.PUBLIC_IP}}"
        export IP="${{parameters.PUBLIC_IP}} $MY_IP"
        echo "IP: $IP"
        az storage account network-rule add --account-name ${{parameters.storage_account_name}} --resource-group ${{parameters.resource_group_name}} --ip-address $MY_IP
        if [ $(az keyvault list --resource-group ${{parameters.resource_group_name}} --query "[?name=='${{parameters.keyvault_name}}'] | length(@)") > 0 ];
          then
            az keyvault network-rule add --resource-group ${{parameters.resource_group_name}} --name ${{parameters.keyvault_name}} --ip-address $MY_IP;
          else
            echo "Resource ${{parameters.keyvault_name}} not found in ${{parameters.resource_group_name}}";
          fi
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=IP_LIST;issecret=false;isoutput=true]$IP"
      failOnStandardError: true
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: check IP
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.service_connection_name}}
      scriptType: "bash"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      inlineScript: |
        echo "Public IP: $IP_LIST"
      failOnStandardError: true
```

EDIT: Added new task to check content of variable and changed variable name to IP_LIST to separate it from parameter used in template.

My idea was to get public IP of agent and add it to the variable created by

`echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PUBLIC_IP;issecret=false;isoutput=true]$IP"`
while

in next jobs use

```
    variables:
      PUBLIC_IP: $[dependencies.Apply.outputs['AddIP.IP_LIST']]
```

and pass it back to add IP template using parameters
That way for each job string should contain IP of current job attached at te end of previous.

My problem is that every time I try to access PUBLIC_IP variable it's always empty.

Comment: `PUBLIC_IP` variable is empty in the next jobs or even empty in the 1st job? Also how are you accessing the variable in the next jobs?

Comment: Even if I add new task to `Add IP template` shown above just to echo $PUBLIC_IP it is empty. but $IP that I pass as a value to the variable is correct.

Comment: As per your latest edit: try referencing the variable like this - `$(AddIP.IP_LIST)` in the inline script.

Comment: Edited: I was able to access value.

Comment: But that don't make any sense for me, I have multiple pipelines where I reference variable set in previous task just by its name, not task.name.

Comment: See this doc, the second point https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#levels-of-output-variables

Comment: Thanks somehow I completely ignored this. This solves some parts of my problem.
I know root cause for second part but I didn't figure how to solve it. 

isoutput=true is only carried across a single job. So if I set variable in job A, I can access it in job B. Problem raise when I have 3 jobs, A,B,C and job B is manual check. Anyway, Thanks for help.